# Adhesive that binds strong but can be cleanly removed

Tags: adhesive, polyurethane, epoxy

I have something I need to bind strong. Much stronger than super glue, but probably less than gorilla glue, although it's not bad if the bind is that strong.
I need it to have a quick setting time, probably within a couple minutes.
I need it to be removable by something less than a chisel.
It doesn't matter if it's hard or rubbery, but it needs to come off pretty clean or close to it. Something like Sikaflex 227 (has a tensile strength of 245 psi, and tensile-sheer strength of 160 psi), although setting time of that is about an hour. I'm hoping to find something inside of 10 minute set time.
Does any such adhesive exist?

Comment: Without more detail, it sounds like a fastener could be a better choice, e.g. a nut and bolt.

Comment: Could you provide a picture or better explain the use for strong glue that is easily removed. To me this is not possible but I am thinking joinery.

Comment: It definitely cannot be bolts. It has to be glue of some sort. Sikaflex 227 is close, but it takes a bit long to set (1 hour if I remember correctly). It still could work for my needs, but I'm hoping to find something that sets within a few minutes instead.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do? Or is this a top secret project? If we knew what you are trying to do, we can help.

Comment: Your requirements are contradictory. Also, you haven't said _what_ you're bonding. Seems important.

Comment: hot melt glue is easy to remove and quick to set. It can be surprisingly strong in _some_ applications, especially non-porous ones where leverage can't break the vacuum, and is waterproof.

Comment: What you're gluing to is a really important consideration in which glue will be appropriate.  If you can't tell us that, we can't do more than guess.

Comment: I'm really not looking for guesses or alternatives to what I'm asking. If you know of glues or epoxies that fit the bill, please answer, otherwise leave it be. There is nothing contradictory about what I'm asking. I did update my question to change "hard" to "strong", which will hopefully eliminate that confusion.

Comment: The right glue will vary depending on materials (which may be 2 of one type or 2 different types): steel, aluminum, brass, glass, wood, fabric, brick, concrete, plastic (and many different types - e.g., some totally compatible with super glue, some totally incompatible, some flexible and some rigid, etc.), etc.

Comment: @Francis, if you think the material you're bonding to is irrelevant to the type of glue that would be appropriate, you might want to take a look at the back of any handy glue bottle -- they ALL list which materials they work well with and which they are not compatible with.  And you're asking for a high strength bond, and the strength of adhesion of ANY glue is going to vary based on what it's adhering TO.  So the only possible answer to your question as currently worded is "it depends".

Comment: If you know of adhesives that fit the bill on any of the types of materials you mentioned, please let me know what they are. Trust me, the material I'm trying to bond is not listed on ANY label anywhere, which is why I'm specifically asking about any adhesives that would fit the bill, then I can decide and/or try to see if they would work.

Comment: Probably something along these lines: https://www.permabond.com/products/flexible-adhesives/ I may try one of those.

Comment: Unfortunately, "shopping" questions are off-topic here. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Seriously? This is not a "shopping" question. I'm looking for adhesive for a real world problem that I currently have, and since it's structure related (trying to adhere 2 solid objects to one another), this should be the perfect place for it.

Comment: Does it need to come off mechanically or chemically? It really does matter what your surfaces are...

Comment: *the material I'm trying to bond is not listed on ANY label anywhere* ???? Really???? If it isn't specifically listed, it must be similar to *something*. Let's see...animal, vegetable, mineral?

Comment: Why? Do you have a book or search engine that only tells you what kind of adhesive exists if you tell it what you're bonding? I seriously don't care what the adhesive bonds. If there's one that meets my requirements, or close to it,I want to know about it. Even if it adheres water to a tree. Why? Because depending on what it's capable of bonding, I may be able to make it work somehow. I already have one I'm going to try.

Comment: Really? Combined, the folks here have years and years of experience (way more than you have been alive.) if you say what materials you are bonding, someone might have done it, helped someone do it, used a product for.... With your vauge description, nobody is going to be able to help you. I am voting to close this topic.

Answer (score 2):

If you need a *glue* glue, then cyanoacrylate may fill the bill.  It's extremely strong (though has narrow tolerances for the mating surfaces, e.g. it *can't* bridge across gaps), and it removes with acetone.   However, acetone can discolor or soften many surfaces.

If you are looking for a method to attach things to surfaces you can't afford to damage, then  you should be using the higher tier of **Gaffer tape**.   Gaffer tape is for temporary attachment of portable lighting in cinema/TV/ENG production, say you're interviewing the CEO in his office, but the room doesn't have nearly enough built-in lighting to shoot.  So you need strong tape to secure some EyLights to his bookcase, *and then, you need the tape to come off cleanly*.

That's what gaffer tape does. That is its one job.

Comment: Do not put this on painted walls!!!

Comment: @DMoore, gaffer tape won't damage painted walls unless the paint was in bad condition to begin with (which I have seen happen, like with new latex paint over an improperly prepped surface).  But any reasonably durable paint will be fine -- I've done it hundreds of times.  Or were you referring to cyanoacrylate/acetone as the thing that should not go on walls?

Comment: I agree that cyanoacrylate is a good choice (provided it is reasonably well suited for the materials being glued) but OP said **Much stronger than super glue**.

Comment: That almost sounds perfect, but this: "Cyanoacrylate glue has a low shearing strength, which has led to its use as a temporary adhesive in cases where the piece needs to be sheared off later". I would definitely need something with a high shearing strength.

Comment: The Sikaflex 227 has a tensile strength of 245 psi, and tensile-sheer strength of 160 psi. That is definitely strong and durable enough for what I'm after, just looking for something that sets faster.

Comment: @NateStrickland - I help out a media group that does news room services and livestreams.   They use gaffer tape all the time and have pissed off clients when it is ripped off of painted walls.   There isn't a lot of other options because the rooms they shoot in are usually metal stud... but yea it doesn't just come off.   It is a really good solution for panels though.

Comment: @DMoore then they're either using the bottom shelf gaffer tape or duct tape, removing it carelessly, or the paint is defective. *cough*lowVOC*cough*  3M Command strips are another example of a product that works fine, but can be botched.

Comment: @DMoore, that's fair; lots of office-type walls are poorly painted with cheap materials so that doesn't surprise me much.  I used to work in theatre lighting, and we'd put gaffer tape on paint all the time, but we tended to use high quality paints and knew how to use them.  All I mean is the advice to not put it on painted walls isn't universal, and you have to consider the condition of the wall in question.

Comment: @NateStrickland, Just an FYI, there are several brands of gap-filling CA glue. Starbond is the brand I'm using.

Comment: @Ring, my comment was about gaffer tape.

Comment: @NateStrickland, ah, it was. I should have pinged manassehkatz